# Index Column Nullable MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, nullable

I have a column of type DateTime being nullable, this same column is indexed.
But when execute the  Select, the index not is used.

```
CREATE TABLE `te3` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dataHora` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`nome` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `IDX_DATAHORA` (`dataHora`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



SELECT *
FROM te3 
where dataHora between '2018-10-11 15:18:16' AND '2018-10-11 15:18:50';
```

Extra
**Using where**

Not use index.

The query is slow, what should I do?
Just remembering that the column has to be nullable

Comment: How much data is in the table?  Indexes are not always used.

Comment: where is proof? can't reproduce http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/362ace/1

Comment: Your table seems to contain 12 rows. You cannot make any generalizations from test on such small tables. Also, can you please clarify "The query is slow", as any measurement above 0.001ms for a query on a table with 12 rows will likely be caused by something else than executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your index could be set as [`INVISIBLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-indexes.html):

> **MySQL supports invisible indexes; that is, indexes that are not used by the optimizer.** The feature applies to indexes other than primary keys (either explicit or implicit).

```
ALTER TABLE te3 ALTER INDEX index_name VISIBLE;
```

Checking:

```
SELECT INDEX_NAME, IS_VISIBLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'te3';
```

Comment: "MySQL supports invisible indexes; that is, indexes that are not used by the optimizer." Indeed but only MySQL 8.0+ supports these queries..

Comment: MySQL might ignore the index for other reasons.

Comment: @SalmanA I am fully aware of that. For example data distribution, non-sargable condtition and so on. That is why I used "could" and not "is"

Comment: You could have confirmed first.

Comment: @SalmanA Confirm what? I posted answer, added query to check if index is visible. Now OP should write a comment (helpful/not this scenario).